# Vaadin PopupDateField not being removed

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

I have some auto-generated code placing the PopupDateField

```
    startonefield = new PopupDateField();
    startonefield.setCaption("Starts on");
    startonefield.setImmediate(false);
    startonefield.setWidth("-1px");
    startonefield.setHeight("-1px");
    mainLayout.addComponent(startonefield, "top:60.0%;left:5.0%;");
```

And here's all the stuff I've tried to remove the datefield

```
    startonefield.setVisible(false);
    this.startonefield.setIcon(null);
    this.startonefield=null;    
    this.mainLayout.removeComponent(startonefield);
    this.mainLayout.removeAllComponents();
```

So what should happen is I call mainLayout.removeAllComponents(); and it's removed, what actually happens is that it removes the object it seems, but I still get a lingering calendar icon that you can click on and select dates, but the textfield that shows the date isn't there - very strange..

I found that by removing mainLayout from it's parent fixes it, so removing the parent of the calendar from it's grandparent fixes the problem, but that's bizarre.

Does anyone know why this happens or a better way of resolving this issue

Comment: Which Vaadin version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

## Example App

I do not know the exact nature of your problem. But here is a single-file complete example showing a PopupDateField being added and removed repeatedly from a layout.

[image]

[image]

The key commands are:

```
this.layout.removeComponent( this.popupDateField );
```

and

```
this.layout.addComponent( this.popupDateField );
```

### Source Code

The following is a complete single-file example app using Vaadin 7.3.6 in Java 8 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. This app is barely modified from the app created by version 1.1.2 of the [Vaadin Plugin for NetBeans 8](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans%7Cthe).

In real work I would separate the layout into its own class file. But for demo purposes, I'll keep to a single file app.

```
package com.example.bogusvaadinapp;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.PopupDateField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@Theme ( "mytheme" )
@SuppressWarnings ( "serial" )
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI
{

    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    final Label label = new Label( "PopupDateField is removed." );
    final PopupDateField popupDateField = new PopupDateField( "SomePopup:" );

    @WebServlet ( value = "/*" , asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( productionMode = false , ui = MyVaadinUI.class , widgetset = "com.example.bogusvaadinapp.AppWidgetSet" )
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest request )
    {
        this.layout.setMargin( true );
        setContent( this.layout );

        Button button = new Button( "Click Me" );
        button.addClickListener( new Button.ClickListener()
        {
            public void buttonClick ( ClickEvent event )
            {
                reactToButtonClick();
            }
        } );
        this.layout.addComponent( button );
        this.layout.addComponent( this.label );
    }

    void reactToButtonClick ()
    {
        // Determine if layout contains our widget.
        Boolean layoutHasPopup = Boolean.FALSE;
        java.util.Iterator<Component> iter = this.layout.iterator();
        while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
            if ( iter.next().equals( this.popupDateField ) ) {
                layoutHasPopup = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Add/Remove widget.
        if ( layoutHasPopup ) {
            // Remove widget.
            this.layout.removeComponent( this.popupDateField );
            this.label.setValue( "PopupDateField gone." );
        } else { // Else layout does not have widget.
            // Add widget.
            this.layout.addComponent( this.popupDateField );
            this.label.setValue( "Showing PopupDateField at " + ZonedDateTime.now() );
        }

    }

}
```